# Finding the maximum and minimum of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1)

Does $[0, \sqrt{2}] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ have a minimum? Maximum?

Minimum is $0$ since $0$ is also a rational number. $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be the maximum because it is not a rational number. How can I go about finding the maximum of this set?

2)

What is the minimum of the set

$\{\left | x \right | + \left | x - 1 \right | + \left | x - 3 \right |: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$

I found the minimum to be 3, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. (Sorry, edit because I misread you). There is no maximum; to prove this, you'll have to use the density of $\mathbb Q$: there are rational numbers arbitrarily close to $\sqrt{2}$ on either side; you can fill in the details.
2. Yes.